# ¿La diferencia entre ARM y AMD64 es una cuestión de cantidad de bits?

Tags: arquitectura, arm

¿Qué diferencia hay entre ARM y AMD64? ¿Es una cuestión de cantidad de bits?

Por ejemplo, una tiene 64, ¿y ARM?

¿Hay más diferencias además de la cantidad de bits? ¿Son muchas diferencias? Y si es así, ¿Cuáles son las principales?

¿Es lo mismo AMD64 que x86_64?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparar un procesador con arquitectura ARM y un procesador con arquitectura x86_64 (o AMD64) es como comparar un avión de pasajeros y un caza: Ciertas características serán similares pero son conceptos totalmente diferentes.

Ahondar en los detalles daría para escribir un libro, así que simplemente listaré las diferencias básicas:

- La empresa ARM licencia (que no fabrica) diseños de CPUs basados en una arquitectura RISC. Entre estos diseños nos podemos encontrar algunos de 32 bits y otros de 64 bits. Empresas que hacen uso de estos diseños: Apple (tanto en móviles como en sus sobremesas y portátiles), Mediatek, Samsung, Qualcomm, NVIDIA, AMD, Huawei...
- AMD diseña y fabrica (en realidad externaliza la fabricación, pero es un detalle menor aquí) su propios procesadores, basados en la arquitectura Intel x86 pero con una extensión propia para usar ​64bits. Se considera una arquitectura de tipo CISC. Intel hace lo mismo: tiene un acuerdo con AMD por el que AMD puede usar la arquitectura x86 y, a cambio, Intel puede usar la extensión AMD64 sobre su arquitectura.
- Los procesadores con arquitectura ARM se caracterizan por su bajo consumo, mientras que los procesadores AMD se centran en la potencia de proceso. Esto hace que los ARM sean los absolutos dominadores en el mercado de los dispositivos móviles mientras que en sobremesa los Intelx86 + AMD64 sean los más usados (hay excepciones en ambos casos).

Por tanto, podemos decir los procesadores AMD64 hablan un lenguaje distinto al que hablan los ARM: un código compilado para uno no es ejecutable en el otro.

El uso o no de 64 bits no es lo que hace que se no puedan entender entre ellos: simplemente indica que las direcciones de memoria usan 64 bits (con lo que pueden direccionar 2<sup>64</sup> bytes (16 exibytes), en lugar de los antiguos 2<sup>32</sup> bytes (4 gigibytes). Además, cada instrucción "normal" (no de punto flotante y no [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD)) ahora puede procesar 64 bits a la vez, con lo que en principio se pueden procesar más datos a la vez (esto no siempre es posible, dependerá de la naturaleza de los datos)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta... Me inquieta algo, ¿ARM de 64 bits es compatible con AMD64? Y si no es así, ¿Hay alguna diferencia que se sepa entre estos?

Comment: He actualizado hablando sobre los 64 bits

Comment: Entiendo que la idea es escribir una respuesta simple, pero decir que 64 bits simplemente indica que las direcciones usan 64 bits es una super-simplificación. Creo que vendría bien mencionar algunos otros temas, como tamaño y cantidad de registros, tamaño de los operadores e instrucciones, diferencia en las convenciones de llamada, cuando menos.

Comment: @jachguate Tienes razón, añadiré algunos detalles más.